# Perform a similar action to cross apply in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a JSON file which needs to essentially perform an action similar to a cross apply in SQL by unpacking a list.

I'm currently using `json_normalize`, however, this does not work with lists so I am looking for a way to flatten out the list column.

How I do it in SQL:

```
CROSS APPLY (SELECT value from STRING_SPLIT(x.list, ',')
```

Current Output in Python:

```
id,name,list
1,tom,[2,4,6]
```

Expected Output in Python:

```
id,name,list
1,tom,2
1,tom,4
1,tom,6
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: use `.explode` `df.explode('list')` it's available in pandas 0.25+ so mind your version

Comment: `df.explode('list')`